# By the end of the Batman Trilogy, how many people came to know the true Identity of Bruce Wayne?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy

In *Batman Begins*, very few people knew about the *true identity* of Bruce Wayne, but as the series progressed the number of people knowing this fact dramatically increased.

Can you provide the list of all the people who knew about his true identity by the end of *The Dark Knight Rises*?

Comment: Before or after the grand opening of Bruce Wayne's Batman Fried Chicken restaurant in downtown Gotham City?

Comment: After Bruce gave up being batman..

Comment: Unless a majority of the city became aware (I've not see the movie] then saying the number *dramatically* increased may be sensationalizing it a little bit.

Comment: @Xantec when talking about Something such as Batman's identity even 6-7 people knowing is dramatic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Off the top of my head (spoilers):

> **Definitely knew**
>   - Alfred Pennyworth
>   - Lucius Fox
>   - Jim Gordon
>   - Selina Kyle
>   - John Blake
>   - Coleman Reese (Unknown whereabouts)
>   - Ra's Al Ghul (Dead)
>   - Talia Al Ghul (Dead)
>   - Bane (Dead)
>   - Rachel Dawes (Dead)
>
>  **Likely knew**
>   - Harvey Dent (Dead)
>   - The Blind Doctor in the Pit (Unknown whereabouts)
>   - The Blind Doctor's assistant (Unknown whereabouts)
>
>  **Possibly knew, unconfirmable**
>   - any of a number of Bane's soldiers (Unknown whereabouts)
>   - any of a number of prisoners in the Pit (Unknown whereabouts)

Comment: >!Lucius Fox definitely knew, I mean he basically supplied all the equipment. (Sorry, spoiler tags don't seem to work in comments.)

Comment: He's one of the ones who never explicitly stated that he knew during any of the movies, albeit the evidence that he did know is pretty strong. I erred on the side of caution. :)

Comment: I always wondered - can we be sure bane died there? how do we really know?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add a few in the "likely knew" section of Gabe Willard great answer:

From the league of shadows:

- The "new" fake Ra's Al Ghu (unkown whereabouts)
- The henchmen that visited Bruce Wayne with Ra's Al Ghu and burned down his house (unkown whereabouts)